# Implement a dictionary using a binary search tree when I have created a bst class

Tags: java

How to implement a dictionary using a binary search tree if I have a `bst` class I've created?

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E> extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>{
   //bst methods(add, remove, find), node class, inOrderIterator, 
}


public class BSTDic<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
   //how would i start it off or would i need to instantiate a bst data? 
   //additionally i need methods such as add(K key, V value), how would  i approach those
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I just need help on a starting point.

Comment: Adding relevant tags in addition to the language will help you get an answer quicker.

Comment: Implementing a dictionary with a BST? Does that mean you want the inherent structure to be a BST or simply use BSTs in your implementation? I ask because one usually use dictionaries with the goal of O(1) complexity. Is your implementation requiring something like O(log(n)) complexity?

Comment: I had eclipse as the language but it was removed dont know why and no specific big O. Simply use BSTs in my implementation.